# How to find log4net location on client machine set with ${LocalAppData}?

Tags: log4net, outlook-addin, appdata

Not sure, if this is the right place to ask this question. I'm working on Outlook Add-In developed by someone. The issue is, on some users' machines, the folder that contains the log files is missing. However, the application seems to be running fine.

Usually, the logfiles are located in

```
<log4net>
    <param name="File" value="${LocalAppData}\MyApp\MyApp_LogFile.log" />
</log4net>
```

Is there a way I can find out what the value of `${LocalAppData}` on an affected client machine?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Open file explorer. Click to folder row. Write `%LocalAppData%\MyApp\` to folder row and press Enter.

**Solution 2**

Run command prompt. Enter command `set` and find environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA`